# Node.js xml2js - When creating sitemap attributes are being ignored

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml, sitemap, xml2js

I'm using node.js and xml2js to create a xml sitemap.xml.

It looks all fine, but when I want to define the attributes e.g.:

```
'$': {
    'xmlns': 'http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9'
},
```

... like this:

```
var obj = {
    'urlset': {
        '$': {
            'xmlns': 'http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9'
        },
        'url': [
            {
                'loc': URL_DOMAIN,
                'changefreq': 'monthly',
                'priority': 1
            },
            {
                'loc': URL_DOMAIN+'/data-privacy',
                'changefreq': 'monthly',
                'priority': 0.5
            }
        ]
    }
};

var builder = new xml2js.Builder({ xmldec: {'version': '1.0', 'encoding': 'UTF-8'} });
var xml = builder.buildObject(obj);

res.header('Content-Type','text/xml').send(xml)
```

... the atributes for the urlset won't render:

```
<urlset>
    <url>
        <loc>http://127.0.0.1:2000</loc>
        <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
        <priority>1</priority>
        </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://127.0.0.1:2000/data-privacy</loc>
        <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
        <priority>0.5</priority>
    </url>
</url>
```

... I would expect:

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
    ...
</url>
```

What am I missing?

... If I do a test:

```
    'urlset': {
        '$': {
            'test': 'test'
        },
```

... it works:

```
<urlset test="test">
    ...
</url>
```

Comment: I don't see any problem with your code. It works absolutely fine for me :). [See here](https://dualhauntingtoolbox.nithinthampi.repl.co). [Code here](https://repl.it/@nithinthampi/DualHauntingToolbox). You probably need to check the server you using. I'm using express in this case. If you are using express, see the versions of packages used as well. Might help.

Comment: ... but in your case I also only see: +<urlset></urlset> as output ... instead of +<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"></urlset> . Is this normal behaviour if I don't see the attribute although its there and applied?

Comment: Most probably a browser issue then. Please check my answer (not really an answer as it doesn't solve your problem). But do follow the steps so that we can conclude that its a browser issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an answer, but an attempt to prove that the OP's code is valid.

I have copied your code and created a REPL .

https://repl.it/@nithinthampi/PeriodicBraveClients.

Click `Run code snippet` below to see that the response do have the xml namespace (You can copy the code an run in your browser console too)

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
```

```js
fetch("https://periodicbraveclients.nithinthampi.repl.co/").then(res => res.text()).then(xml => console.log(xml))
```

Probably got something to do with browser may be. Below is my browser screenshot.

[image: This is what I see in browser]